# Download two files and make it as a zip file

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am creating a website. My two files are in different locations, I want to zip the two files into a single zip file. If i click the download option, the files in two different locations can be downloaded into a single zip file and provided to the user. How to do it in JSP?

I tried it in jsp but i dont know how to do...

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.io.BufferedReader,java.io.IOException,java.io.InputStreamReader,java.util.Enumeration,java.util.zip.*,java.util.zip.ZipFile"%>
<html>
<body>
<% 
//getting the zip file path

String path=request.getParameter("path");
response.setContentType("application/zip");
//response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + path + "\"");
byte[] _buf = new byte[1024];
//zos is used to write files in zip
ZipOutputStream zos = null;
//zip is used to read files 
ZipInputStream zis = null;
boolean bsuccess = true;
zos = new ZipOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream("D:/temp/SSO.zip"));
zis = new ZipInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(path));
ZipEntry ze = null;

while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
String fname = ze.getName();
if (fname!=null)
{
//copy the entry from zis to zos
int bytes = 0;
//deal with password protected files
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fname));
while ((bytes = zis.read(_buf)) > 0)
{
zos.write(_buf, 0, bytes);
}
zis.closeEntry();
zos.closeEntry();

}
}
if (zis != null)
zis.close();
if (zos != null)
zos.close();
%>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. show us what have you tried so far

Comment: ... Zip them together using the Java Zip API then stream it to the client. Both these things are easily searchable, and have examples. Although this type of work really belongs outside the view layer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the part where you write the zip file out to response.getOutputStream(), which requires, by the way, that you haven't printed anything to the page yet. If you already printed stuff, you'll get an error that response.getOutputStream() was already called.

In other words, take out

```
<html>
<body>
```

Replace:

```
zos = new ZipOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream("D:/temp/SSO.zip"));
```

With:

```
zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```